# Change the text color of the days in the previous and following months inside the RangePicker component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, antd

I want to change the following Saturday and Sunday text colors on the RangePicker, but my condition is in the Start and End Dates of the RangePicker, the Saturday and Sunday days from the last month and previous month of it should have a lighter color. How can I implement this?

I want to change the text colors of the following Saturdays and Sundays in the RangePicker. However, I have a condition: in the Start and End Dates of the RangePicker, the Saturday and Sunday days from the last and following months should have lighter colors.

[Code Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jtpazq?file=demo.js)

The RangePicker component should look like this:

[Sample 1 Image, but still lacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB0zx.png)
[Sample 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pvuo.png)

For example:

**Start Date Month (June):**

- June's Saturday and Sunday = Blue and red
- July's Saturday and Sunday = light blue and light red
- May's Saturday and Sunday = light blue and light red

**End Date Month (July):**

- July's Saturday and Sunday = Blue and red
- August's Saturday and Sunday = light blue and light red
- June's Saturday and Sunday = light blue and light red

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set different style for Saturday and Sunday.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DatePicker, Space } from 'antd';
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

const App = () => {
  const [isDateMode, setIsDateMode] = useState(true);

  const onPanelChange = (value, mode) => {
    if (mode[0] === 'date' && mode[1] === 'date') {
      setIsDateMode(true);
    } else {
      setIsDateMode(false);
    }
  };
  const cellRender = (current, info) => {
    if (!isDateMode) {
      return info.originNode;
    }
    let className = 'ant-picker-cell-inner';
    if (current.day() === 6) {
      className += ' ant-picker-cell-sa';
    } else if (current.day() === 0) {
      className += ' ant-picker-cell-su';
    }
    return <div className={className}>{current.date()}</div>;
  };

  return (
    <Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
      <RangePicker cellRender={cellRender} onPanelChange={onPanelChange} />
      <style>
        {`
          .ant-picker-cell:not(.ant-picker-cell-in-view)
          .ant-picker-cell-inner.ant-picker-cell-sa {
            color: lightblue;
          }

          .ant-picker-cell.ant-picker-cell-in-view
          .ant-picker-cell-inner.ant-picker-cell-sa {
            color: blue;
          }

          .ant-picker-cell:not(.ant-picker-cell-in-view)
          .ant-picker-cell-inner.ant-picker-cell-su {
            color: #ffcccb;
          }

          .ant-picker-cell.ant-picker-cell-in-view
          .ant-picker-cell-inner.ant-picker-cell-su {
            color: red;
          }
          `}
      </style>
    </Space>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Code Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jtpazq-yigqcb?file=demo.js)

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but what I want to implement is to include it on the End Date Picker and consider when the user changes months, for example, when the user changes the Start date month to November, that distinction of colors should also be there, not making all the days (Sat and Sun) in November lighter. Like tracking what month it is currently on the Start and End Date picker. Is that possible?

Comment: @Zexol yes, it's possible, I have edited my answer.